# A site loads faster when a jQuery file is not cached?

Tags: jquery, performance, caching

I have a jQuery file `jquery.min.js` that used to slow my website down. I tried all sorts of things. I tried to minify it, I tried to use a different library nothing really made a difference. So I finally tried this: `<script src="jquery.min.js?session=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>` Now that it loads like a fresh file on each visit the issue seems to be gone. What is the reason behind this? Was the caching this file the real issue? It makes very little sense to me.

Comment: My guess it it's due to an extension

Comment: @Saikiran Can you elaborate?